# Function repetition speed up python (using multiprocessing??)

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

I want to repeat same function using list component as input variable.
I make a source below.

```
def sample_function(a,b,c):
    ~~~
    return A

list_list=pd.DataFrame()
q=2
r=3
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    p=check[i]
    result=sample_function(p,q,r)
    list_list=list_list.append(result)
```

But this work takes a lot of time....

How can I decrease time for this work?

`check=['AA','BB','CC','DD',,,]`

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities. Multiprocessing is one possibility, but it may or may not be applicable depending on what you do in the function. You should provide the snippet that runs as-is, and make it clear what you do in the sample function and your desired outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Pool from `multiprocessing`. Here is a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

def sample_function(a,b,c):
    a=check[a]
    ~~~
    return result

list_list=pd.DataFrame()

list_list = []
pool = Pool(len(list))
results = pool.map(sample_function, range(0,len(list), q, r)

list_list = pd.concat(results)
```

Comment: Hmm... your answer nicely explains how to use multiprocessing. But when I see using `append` to a dataframe inside a loop, I really think that most of the time is likely to be spent there. Said differently you are probably optimizing for seconds, while minutes are being wasted elsewhere...

Comment: You can always return the list from function. But it will gives you another list of returned items and they need to be appended using loops again. In my opinion given one is one of the way to avoid extra hassle.

Comment: Here I have edited the code and this may be more efficient.

Comment: What I meant if that when using pandas, Python level loops are to be avoided as much as possible. Pandas uses the highly optimized `numpy` modules and provides *vectorized* methods handling loops at C level. You generally have orders of magnitude in term of performance between vectorized and non vectorized code.

Comment: You have already done a good job... what is lacking from your post is the pandas part.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I see. You can avoid using python loop by using `pandas.concat` to concat list of dataframes. Check the edited code.

Comment: @RafatHasan thx for your answer. but I have another question. what is a=check[a]??

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is the same array you used inside for loop `p=check[i]` but in this I am using it inside function.